# Custom class shares name with C# class

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking through the codebase left behind by my predecessor and got confused by the following class definition, which appears to copy a Microsoft defined class:

```
//...
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Processes;
public class Process
{
    public Process(ProcessType processType, ILogger log)
    {
        this.ProcessType = processType;
        this.StopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        this.PopulateProcessors();

        Log.Process = this;
        Log.Logger = log;
    }
//...
}
```

The files goes on for awhile and includes a definition for a method called `Start()`, amongst others.
I'm confused because Microsoft already defines a `Process` class, with a `Start()` method, in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, which is being used here.

So how can we be defining a class that already exists, and is not being inherited? There's clearly a gap in my knowledge. What am I missing here?

Comment: thats in the `Processes` namespace - so its fine to reuse names across namespaces

Comment: @DanielA.White well that's a facepalm moment. Thank you, that makes complete sense!

Comment: Once we were using Subsonic to auto-gen POCOs from DB objects.  My genius boss named a table "System".  When we regened the POCOs, my IDE lit up like a Christmas tree.  Took me a few minutes to figure out why EVERYTHING was an error because it all inherits from System

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple classes with the same name, as long as they have different namespaces. For example:

```
System.Threading.Timer;
System.Windows.Forms.Timer;
```

These namespaces both have a class called `Timer`. This would normally cause ambiguity, but you can use both of them by doing this:

```
using ThreadingTimer = System.Threading.Timer;
using FormsTimer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;

void StartFormsTimer()
{
    FormsTimer myFormsTimer = new FormsTimer();
    myFormsTimer.Interval = 1000;
    myFormsTimer.Start();
}
```

Or, you can add the namespace every time you use `Timer`:

```
System.Threading.Timer threadingTimer = new System.Threading.Timer();
System.Windows.Forms.Timer formsTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
```

It's a matter of personal preference. I generally try to avoid having multiple classes with the same name to avoid confusion.

Comment: This is great! Thank you, the namespaces make sense. After looking through the project, I realized this is the only file that uses `System.Diagnostics`, and that's just for the `StopWatch`. Every other file just uses the Processes namespace.

Also, that's good advice on clarifying ambiguous method names. I didn't know you could do that, but it will probly come in handy at some point.